# wordpress multisite on openshift not working

Tags: wordpress, openshift

I want to enable wordpress multisite on openshift hosting

I have added in wp-config.php  file

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
```

But this has no effect i can't see network seetings in wordpress admin, under tools menu

Has openshift disabled wordpress multisite ?

Please note that i am in free plan, and i'm sure i was editing the right wp-config.php file through ftp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing an rhc app restart, or rhc app stop && rhc app start on your application and see if that helps reload the configuration.  When you do a WordPress update you have to do a restart also.

Comment: Thanks, i have removed entirelly the app then added it many times, i have also installed wordpress from github, no way, but i will try to do rhc app start and stop to see